# Android - 3D pie chart

Tags: android, charts, 3d, clickable, pie-chart

**My requirements are :**

1. 3D pie chart for android device.
2. Should work offline.
3. Clickable on individual pie.
4. Pie should look like : 
   [image]

**Here Is quick overview of problems I am facing to draw 3d pie chart.**

1. **Orson Charts** - I found one library which can satisfy my need but it is paid (High rates). (http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/android/index.html)
2. **Google chart library** - which draws pie chart using API call which we don't want . Our application should work offline. (https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart
3. **jFreeChart** - This is java library but uses swing packages to draw graphs. Swing is not included in android so there is limitation to use this library. (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartPieChart3DDemo2withRotation.htm)
4. **aFreeChart** - This is designed for android which used above (jFreeChart) library but they have not included 3D drawing facility for pie chart. (http://afreechart.googlecode.com/svn/doc/screenshot/index.html)

Please suggest me if there is any possibility of using any library..

Comment: Pie charts are one of the worst ways to visually represent this kind of information.  You'd be well served to consider another graphic.  You should also consider D3: http://d3js.org/

Comment: GraphView library is one of them which works offline in android.
also refer to these links .
https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-line-graph-using-graphview-library-tutorial/
http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/create-a-real-time-line-graph-in-android-with-graphview/ hope this helps.

Comment: @Chavan Parmeshwar did you got an answer for your question???

Comment: @KJEjava48 no I skipped to use pie chart.